# Обязательно ли тире в следующем примере?

Tags: тире

В данных конструкциях (источники в конце монографии) тире факультативно или обязательно? Пример: Государственный архив Вологодской области (далее - ГАВО) или (далее ГАВО)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исходить непосредственно из правил орфографии и пунктуации, то тире обязательно, поскольку тут явно пропущен один (или более) членов. Но прямых указаний на обязательность тире я не нашел, возможно надо смотреть более специализированные источники по оформлению печатных работ.

Все, что удалось найти: [сокращения](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjJhcbm27PdAhVMDcAKHdRFD7cQFjABegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hse.ru%2Fdata%2F2013%2F05%2F24%2F1298932952%2F%25D0%259F%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B0%2520%25D0%25BE%25D1%2584%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D0%25BC%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F%2520%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%2583%25D1%2587%25D0%25BD%25D1%258B%25D1%2585%2520%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B1%25D0%25BE%25D1%2582.ppt&usg=AOvVaw2hm5fmX91a_NvIInR84Ph7).
Здесь тире используется последовательно, но авторитетность источника, понятно, невысокая.

Answer (score 0):

Я, редактор, категорически не ставлю никаких тире, вот как здесь:

[Москва, Лондон, далее везде…](https://echo.msk.ru/programs/albac/2274774-echo/)

Но, возможно, исчерпывающим ответом для Вас будет приводимое Справкой Грамоты.ру:

[**Вопрос № 289436**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=289436)

*В тексте возникла необходимость сократить название документа: требования к независимым аттестационно-методическим центрам (далее - НАМЦ). Надо ли перед сокращением ставить тире? Спасибо.*

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

*Тире ставится.*

Подробнее, с примерами, см. ***[здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=(%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20-)***.

Comment: В аналогичных примерах Справка допускает, что "тире факультативно" и "без тире". Я так понимаю, что четкого правила все-таки нет.

Comment: Саш, а у меня по ссылочке "здесь" сплошь тире навязывают; я не нашла "факультативно", это мой личный бунт.

Comment: Ответы №№ 200150, 208448, 231470, 251569. Зависит от отвечающего, видимо.

Comment: ЗдОрово! Спасибо! Я а) не одинока и б) не волюнтаристка! )))